# How to create Coredata entity and attributes dynamically in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-data

Actully my data is coming from server and its depend upon the data to create the number of attribute and entity ...

Answer (score 1):

The piece you want to modify is the `NSManagedObjectModel`. This cannot be modified once it is in use, however, since it changes the database schema. You have to make a copy of the model, modify it, convert all the data, and then switch to the new model. The following pages should be helpful:

- [NSManagedObjectModel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
- [Using a Managed Object Model](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdUsingMOM.html)
- [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks,But i need more clear information about Programetically creating the core data model and attributes.

Answer (score 0):

sorry but this is not possible.

you need to make entity and attributes static with max of possibility as per your requirement and work with only those attributes that you need at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you create your core data model in sort of Key/Value entities.

E.g: 
CarEntity has 2 attributes: key/value (both of type string)

Values in CarEntity could be:

- "Model","VW"
- "Power","7 kW"
- "whatever key","whatever value"

Would that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can create/modify the entity, before you assign the ManagedObjectModel to the NSPersistentStoreCoordinator , here is a sample code.

NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CoreDataDemoModel" withExtension:@"momd"];
    NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];

```
NSEntityDescription *runEntity = [[NSEntityDescription alloc] init];
[runEntity setName:@"Run"];
[runEntity setManagedObjectClassName:@"Run"];
[mom setEntities:@[runEntity]];

NSMutableArray *runProperties = [NSMutableArray array];

NSAttributeDescription *dateAttribute = [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
[runProperties addObject:dateAttribute];
[dateAttribute setName:@"date"];
[dateAttribute setAttributeType:NSDateAttributeType];
[dateAttribute setOptional:NO];

NSAttributeDescription *idAttribute= [[NSAttributeDescription alloc] init];
[runProperties addObject:idAttribute];
[idAttribute setName:@"processID"];
[idAttribute setAttributeType:NSInteger32AttributeType];
[idAttribute setOptional:NO];
[idAttribute setDefaultValue:@0];

[runEntity setProperties:runProperties];

NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *store = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom];

NSError *error = nil;
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataDemoModel.sqlite"];
[store addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
[context setPersistentStoreCoordinator:store];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Managed object models are editable until they are used by an object graph manager (a managed object context or a persistent store coordinator). This allows you to create or modify them dynamically until their first use. However, once a model is being used, it must not be changed. This is enforced at runtime—when the object manager first fetches data using a model, the whole of that model becomes uneditable. Any attempt to mutate a model or any of its sub-objects after that point throws an exception. If you need to modify a model that’s in use, create a copy, modify the copy, and then discard the objects with the old model.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel